# Changing SimpleDateFormat from ..Z to ...+00:00

Tags: java, spring-boot, timezone, assertion

I'm having trouble with my Tests for my Java Spring Boot API.
The error is the following:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$._embedded.boats[0].dateBoatConstruction"
Expected: is "2021-03-04T01:27:38.734Z"
     but: was "2021-03-04T01:27:38.734+00:00"
```

To try to get it to have the right formatting, I've done the following:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+0000");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
df.setTimeZone(tz);
```

According to [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), it should return the correct format:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" ===  2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00
```

This is how the relevant code fragment is written:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.boats[0].dateBoatConstruction", is(df.format(currentDate))))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Comment: @ShekharRai I'm on Java Version 15, Spring Boot 2.4.3 and the latest `spring-boot-starter-test`

Comment: Could you please make sure that both production code and test case have the same date-formatting? There could be some kind of manipulation while processing the date or while sending it back as the response.

Comment: @ShekharRai It's what I was trying to achieve - however I've been made aware of `java.time.Instant`, which I will be using from now on. This makes this question obsolete. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: hmmm! Nice one!

Comment: You may want to delete the question? You have got a delete link under it. And congrats on moving to java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Answer (score 0):

I was unaware of the "new" `java.time.Instant`, so I've migrated my code to it.